# Cocoa always run app with permissions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How do I make it so that every time I run my app it runs as administrator? For example, when I run on xcode I have `read/write` privileges, but when I double-click on the app to run it I only have `read` privileges. How do I make it always launch with `read/write` privileges?

Comment: is this for yourself or is this an app you're going to ship?  additionally, is this an app you're going to put up on the Apple App Store?

Comment: This app is more for testing purposes, and I only have an iOS account, so it's not going on the app store. I'd just like to be able to actually use it without having to run it through xcode every time.

Comment: You always have read write privileges to your app's container in a sandboxed environment.  What exactly are you trying to write to that the system won't let you?

Comment: For example, I open a text file in like `/Users/macuser/text.txt` and try to write something, it works when I'm running out of Xcode, but now when I just run it from finder.

Comment: Is “macuser” there another user, or yourself? I'm inclined to think that this is a sandboxing issue and the answer, if this is your own app not destined for the App Store, is “then don't do that”. Conversely, if you do want to stay sandboxed, then you are just going to have to open files in your app by means other than hard-coding or keying in paths. And if “macuser” is a different user, then this isn't a sandboxing issue and you can disregard this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Get Info" on your app icon and then add "Administrator" as the owner to your app.  Like this:

[image: Add new owner this way]